# pg_fetch_array() error

Tags: php, postgresql, syntax-error

I tried to run this code to fill up a dropdown menu with data out of my database:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["table"], $_GET["field"]))
        {
        require "opendb.php";

        $table = $_GET["table"];
        $field = $_GET["field"];

        $query =    "select '{$field}'
                    from '{$table}' "; 

        $data =  pg_query($conn, $query);

        $attribute_names = array();

        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($data))
        {
            array_push($attribute_names, $row[$field]);
        }

        print_r($row);

        echo json_encode($attribute_names);

        require "closedb.php";
    }
?>
```

But I get this **error**:

> pg_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   ...

The thing is don't know if I can use teh variable $field in $row liike that.
So i don't know if this is possible `$row[$field]` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$query =    "select '{$field}'
                    from '{$table}' ";
```

To

```
$query =    "select `{$field}`
                    from `{$table}` ";
```

`Table Name` & `Column Name` Are Not Denoted Through `'`. Instead Use Backtick(`)

Find `Backtick` in keyboard :

[image]

**EDIT**

Error coming because `field/column name` or `table name` doesn't exist in your query. Try with `echo "select {$field} from {$table} ";`. And, see what output it comes and run this output in **phpmyadmin** and you will get the exact error regarding query.

This is right `$row[$field]`

Comment: I know where can i find the Backtick but it doesn't solve my syntax error.

Comment: What error you are getting ? Same ? @L.Grunn. You know where to find backtick is OK. This answer is not only for you. It is for all user who search for an answer.

Comment: Error coming because your `field name/column name` or `table name` doesn't exist in your query. I tried. *It works for me.* @L.Grunn. Try with `echo "select {$field} from {$table} ";` and see what output it comes.

Comment: How you knew it's not pushing @L.Grunn

Comment: Nvm it did push, but my browser wasn't refreshing. Thanks for the help Nana

Comment: @L.Grunn :  If this answer helped you. Please mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. *~Thanks*

Comment: Yeah butf or me the answer was to use no quotes. So it's not entirely correct.

Comment: As you wish @L.Grunn `:D`